# Dense TextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

In the old View system, we can make `TextInputLayout` dense using style `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense`.

How can I create a dense variant of `TextField` in Compose?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `1.2.0-alpha04` you can use the **`TextFieldDecorationBox`** together with `BasicTextField` to build a custom text field based on Material Design text fields.

To create a dense text field, use **`contentPadding`** parameter to decrease the paddings around the input field.

Something like:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val singleLine = true
val enabled = true
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
BasicTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    modifier = Modifier
        .indicatorLine(enabled, false, interactionSource, TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors())
        .background(
            TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors().backgroundColor(enabled).value,
            TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldShape
        )
        .width(TextFieldDefaults.MinWidth),
    singleLine = singleLine,
    interactionSource = interactionSource
) { innerTextField ->
    TextFieldDecorationBox(
        value = text,
        innerTextField = innerTextField,
        enabled = enabled,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        label = { Text("Label") },
        contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithLabelPadding(
            start = 4.dp,
            end = 4.dp,
            bottom = 4.dp // make it dense
        )
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: TextFieldDecorationBox is deprecate, what is alternative?

Comment: OutlinedTextfieldDefaults.DecorationBox is not deprecated